# What is the significance of the glowing orb at the end of the Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

At the end of the Phantom Menace, at the celebration on Naboo, Boss Nass (if memory serves), holds aloft a great, glowing orb. I remember reading at the time that Lucas had some great significance assigned to the orb, and that he would address it later in the trilogy. To my recollection, he never did.

Does anyone know, perhaps from the novelization or other extracinematic sources, what it was supposed to be or mean?

[image]

Comment: what a nice old Gungan

Comment: It looks like the shield that the Gungans use. That was also crucial to victory.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

That would be the [Globe of Peace](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Globe_of_Peace):

> The Globe of Peace was a relic of the Naboo people. It resembled a small sphere which glowed with an iridescent light and symbolized the years of peace that reigned on the planet. As a gesture of good faith and continued relations with the Gungan people, Queen Padmé Amidala presented the globe to Boss Rugor Nass.

As to its later significance.. I can see all sorts of ways it could have been used.. Shattered by the people of Naboo, symbolically indicating their plan... Shattering on its own as peace fails.  Anakin shattering it as one of his first acts as Vader, etc.. Many dramatic possibilities... But, so far as I recall, none of them ever happened.. I think the idea didn't pan out, plot-wise, and Lucas just dropped it.