# What was the celebration at the end of Star Wars Phantom Menace?

Tags: star-wars, the-phantom-menace

In this [link](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_I_The_Phantom_Menace)  I find...

> The Naboo and Gungans organize a great victory celebration on the
>   streets of Theed, in front on the palace. Obi-Wan and Anakin are
>   present, the younger now wearing formal Jedi attire, and in his hair
>   is a special braid: the mark of a Jedi Padawan. Queen Amidala presents
>   a gift of appreciation and friendship to Boss Nass and the Gungan
>   people.

The thing is that I interpret the celebration at the end of Star Wars Phantom Menace to be the celebration of peace between the Naboo and the Gungans. The fact that the sparkling globe is a symbol of the peace between the Naboo and the Gungans (This [answer link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/8226/17024)) points to this peace interpretation. The quote above points towards a victory celebration and a celebration of peace. Perhaps it is both then. I called it a celebration in my question. Was it an military awards ceremony like at the end of ANH? What was the celebration at the end of Star Wars Phantom Menace?

Comment: I assume they were celebrating their victory in the battle with the droid army they had just won.

Comment: @Jeeped Yep, I am a bad speller.. will fix...

Comment: @PaulL Yes but I can make assumptions too. Is there an official answer? a semi official answer?

Comment: It wa the end of the movie. Reason enough to celebrate.

Comment: @Wikis Yes, but that is out of universe. :-)

Comment: It looked like a celebration but it was actually a funeral for the death of respect for Lucas across the globe.

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Comment: Sorry, kind of forgot about the question... I guess *the* answer is not as clear cut as I might have hoped, not by a fault of yours but that is just the way it is. That the parade and celebration was both. I was thinking it might be a smaller celebration of the Gungan and Naboo where the alliance was the main reason. It seems the answer is that it was a celebration of both victory and alliance rather than one or the other.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The film's [official novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_I:_The_Phantom_Menace_(novel)) notes that the parade was largely intended to cement the relationship between the Naboo and the Gungans and a celebration of their military victory over their robotic occupiers:

> **There was a grand parade the following day to publicly recognize the
>   newfound alliance of the Naboo and Gungan peoples, to celebrate their
>   hard-fought victory over the Trade Federation invaders, and to honor
>   those who had fought to secure the planet’s freedom.** Crowds lined the
>   streets of Theed as columns of Gungan warriors astride kaadu and Naboo
>   soldiers aboard speeders rode through the city to the sounds of
>   cheering and singing.

The [Starwars.com](http://www.starwars.com/films/star-wars-episode-1-the-phantom-manace-story-gallery) site offers this snippet about the event:

[image]